# How to display image from JSON object in Angular

Tags: angular, nestjs

I have a page where I want to show images or videos shared by various people. I am not able to fetch image from rest API. API looks like

```
 {
"status": "success",
"code": 200,
"response": [
{
  "Id": 91,
  "Media": [
    {
      "ImagePath": "http:/13.232.25.79:4105/files/7/7051252eae6820fd3309120d72fe2978.jpg",
      "LikeCount": 0,
      "Comment": ""
    },
    {
      "ImagePath": "http:/13.232.25.79:4105/files/7/car.jpg",
      "LikeCount": 0,
      "Comment": ""
    }
  ],
  "CandidateId": 7,
  "Message": "hello",
  "CreatedAt": "2020-12-15T11:31:12.488Z",
  "Candidates": {
    "Id": 7,
    "FirstName": "Rajesh",
    "LastName": "Bhati"
      }
   }
   ],
   "error": [],
  "message": "Media list"
  }
```

I have tried following code

*my component.html*

```
 <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let candidateMedia of sharedMedia">
    <div class="container_box">
         <p>{{candidateMedia.Candidates.FirstName }}         
          {{candidateMedia.Candidates.LastName }} shares following post</p>
       <img src="{{filteredImages(candidateMedia.Media.ImagePath)}}">
   </div>
 </div>
```

*my componenet.ts file*

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.socialService.getMedia().subscribe((res: any) => {
  this.sharedMedia = res.payload
})
 }

  filteredImages(value) {
const imageString = value.replace('13.232.25.79:4600/', '')
return imageString
}
```

Comment: After replacing the substring, `http:/13.232.25.79:4105/files/7/7051252eae6820fd3309120d72fe2978.jpg` becomes `http:/files/7/7051252eae6820fd3309120d72fe2978.jpg`. This doesn't make any sense. May I know why?

Comment: @Arcteezy earlier image url was "http:/13.232.25.79:4600/13.232.25.79:4105/files/7/20161103_100735.jpg". Thats why i have used replace method to remove this "13.232.25.79:4600/" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to iterate through the Media array to get the corresponding objects provide it should contain the proper image url

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let candidateMedia of sharedMedia">
    <div class="container_box">
        <p>{{candidateMedia.Candidates.FirstName }}
            {{candidateMedia.Candidates.LastName }} shares following post</p>
        <img *ngFor="let img of candidateMedia.Media" [src]="img.ImagePath">
    </div>
</div>
```

and in your API data, one `/` is missing. In that case

```
<div class="form-group" *ngFor="let candidateMedia of sharedMedia">
    <div class="container_box">
        <p>{{candidateMedia.Candidates.FirstName }}
            {{candidateMedia.Candidates.LastName }} shares following post</p>
        <img *ngFor="let img of candidateMedia.Media" src="{{filteredImages(img.ImagePath)}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

**In ts**

```
filteredImages(value) {
    const imageString = value.replace('http:/13.232.25.79:4105', 'http://13.232.25.79:4105')
    return imageString
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your code below:

```html
 <img src="{{filteredImages(candidateMedia.Media.ImagePath)}}">
```

Make sure to check your response. I mean your Media is an `array`, not an `object`. So if you want to get and show the first image, maybe you can use `index` of that image, or if you want to show all image, make sure to add `*ngFor` for that's Media.

**Only For First Image:**

```
 <img src="{{filteredImages(candidateMedia.Media[0].ImagePath)}}">
```

**For All Image:**

```
 <img *ngFor="let media of candidateMedia.Media" src="{{filteredImages(media.ImagePath)}}">
```

**Updated:** Add `Pipe`

If you want to use pipe, to resolve your imagePath, you can use this pipe below:

Create `resolve-image-path.pipe.ts` and paste this code below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'resolveImagePath'})
export class ResolveImagePath implements PipeTransform {
    transform(imagePath: string): string {
        const urlSplit = imagePath.split('/');
        const indexOfFiles = urlSplit.indexOf('files');
        return urlSplit.splice(indexOfFiles).join('/');
    }
}
```

After that, you can `declare` that pipe in your `module.ts`, after that, you can call that pipe to resolve your image path. **For an example:**

```
 <img *ngFor="let media of candidateMedia.Media" src="{{media.ImagePath | resolveImagePath}}">
```

Now, you can try your own.

Comment: What is the reason? If image broken, it's mean the code above it's working. Make sure to the pipeline, add your spesific image host address : return `your-host-address/` + urlSplit.splice(indexOfFiles).join('/')